# Azure - How to get a list of federated databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, sql-azure-federations

In SQL Management studio, when connected to an Azure db, you can expand the 'Federations' folder and get a list of all federated databases. I'm trying to figure out the backing query that would find that info, but I'm having very limited success.

Could anyone point me at a table which may have that info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to [this url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh597455.aspx).

I wanted the `sys.federations` and `sys.federation_distributions` tables.